# How to give a path to a link with filter?

Tags: views, uri

I am trying to give a path to a submenu with Filter(field) as

my-view&field_subject=C

but it shows error like 'path is either invalid or you do not have access to it.'

when i give 'my-view' it works perfectly.

But i want to show the view with 'Subject' column with Value C only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'&' is used to divide query parameters, to split the page and parameters, use '?'

e.g.
my-view?field_subject=C